# Wordpress Different Page for Blog

Tags: wordpress

I'm creating a Wordpress site, and I have a static page for the homepage, and I have the blog at /journal.

I have changed the settings in Settings -> Reading where I'm setting a static page for my front page, and my Journal page for my posts page.

The issue is with single posts. Single posts lose the /journal and go back to the root of the site.

For example, when you are reading a post on /journal, and then you click to view the post, it goes to /2015/02/hello-world. I need it to stay under /journal and instead link to /journal/2015/02/hello-world.

Any idea how to do this?

I have tried changing the Custom Structure under Settings -> Permalinks to /journal/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%/, but then other pages on the site (not blog posts) are getting /journal added to the URL.

Comment: I use /journal/%postname%/ and it works as expected (single posts get the blog root, while pages do not).

Comment: I've realized my issue lies with custom post types. My custom post type URLs are getting the /journal/ tacked to the beginning.

Comment: Normally, when I create a custom post type, I also create a "permastructure" for it. It's not the easiest thing to get right though. You might look at add_rewrite_tag, add_rewrite_rule, and add_permastruct.